# I can't understand this comparing code in Golfscript

Tags: compare, golfscript

I saw `~.2$<@@if` this code being called comparing code.
It does work, but I know `@` means

> Rotates the top 3 elements of the stack so that the 3rd down is now on top.

and I can't understand how it works.
Can anyone please explain what `@` is in this code?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Now I know, `@` is literally rotating.
`.2$<` returns 1 if the left arg is bigger, and 0 if the right one is bigger.
`@@` makes the input `a b` to `1 a b` or `0 a b`.
The code would say `a` when the condition is 1, or `b` when 0.